# Date range comparison unexpected output despite inclusion of target date

Tags: php, php-carbon

I'm encountering an unexpected outcome when attempting to compare dates in my PHP code. Here's what I'm doing:

```
<?php
$date = Carbon::now()->locale('fr_FR');
$date->subMonth();
$previousMonth = ucfirst($date->monthName) . ' ' . $date->year;
$currentDate = Carbon::now()->locale('fr_FR');
$currentDate->firstOfMonth();
$firstDayOfPreviousMonth = $currentDate->subMonth()->firstOfMonth(); // "2024-02-01"
$lastDayOfPreviousMonth = $firstDayOfPreviousMonth->copy()->lastOfMonth(); // "2024-02-29"

$carbonSubmissionTime = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(1709216823); // "2024-02-29"
if ($carbonSubmissionTime->gte($firstDayOfPreviousMonth) && $carbonSubmissionTime->lte($lastDayOfPreviousMonth)) {
    echo "ok";
}else{
    echo "nok";
}
```

You can test the code in: https://play.phpsandbox.io/embed/nesbot/carbon

The expectation is to receive "ok" because "2024-02-29" falls within the range of "2024-02-01" and "2024-02-29". However, the actual result is "nok".

What might be causing this discrepancy?

**EDIT**

I also tried using `betweenIncluded` but gives the same result:

```
if($carbonSubmissionTime->betweenIncluded($firstDayOfPreviousMonth, $lastDayOfPreviousMonth)){}
```

Comment: I wonder if this is an issue with Times. if your range is `2024-02-01 00:00:00` and `2024-02-29 00:00:00`, and the date you're checking is `2024-02-29 00:00:01` (or any other time besides `00:00:00`), that would indeed fail. If you do `->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`, you might see your problem.

Comment: Yes, but it's equal to the same date, how can i include it

Comment: Doesn't matter if the date is the same, the time is not, and `2024-02-29 00:00:01` (or any other time) is **NOT** between `2024-02-01 00:00:00` and `2024-02-29 00:00:00`. To make the date range inclusive, there's the `startOfDay()` and `endOfDay()` functions (as illustrated below), or you set `->startOfDay()` on all of your Carbon instances. Welcome to the wonderful world of DateTime manipulation and comparison 

Comment: Simplest solution with your current code would be to add `->endOfDay()` to `$lastDayOfPreviousMonth` to make it `2024-02-29 23:59:59`, like  `$lastDayOfPreviousMonth = $firstDayOfPreviousMonth->copy()->lastOfMonth()->endOfDay();`, but the answer below is a pretty great reference for how to properly handle this rather annoying, but common case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discrepancy comes from the fact that `$carbonSubmissionTime` also has a time component to it where `$lastDayOfPreviousMonth` has its time set to `00:00:00`.

If we add the following debug statements before the comparison, the issue is apparent:

```
echo "The submission time is ", $carbonSubmissionTime->toDateTimeString(), "\n";
echo "First day of previous month is ", $firstDayOfPreviousMonth->toDateTimeString(), "\n";
echo "Last day of previous month is ", $lastDayOfPreviousMonth->toDateTimeString(), "\n";
```

This yields:

> The submission time is 2024-02-29 14:27:03
>
> First day of previous month is 2024-02-01 00:00:00
>
> Last day of previous month is 2024-02-29 00:00:00

Either change the last day of the previous month to have a time of 23:59:59, or zero out the time like so:

```
$carbonSubmissionTime = $carbonSubmissionTime->startOfDay(); // "2024-02-29 00:00:00"
```

Making either of those changes produces the desired output.

A basic date string comparison also works:

```
if (
    $carbonSubmissionTime->toDateString() >= $firstDayOfPreviousMonth->toDateString()
    && $carbonSubmissionTime->toDateString() <= $lastDayOfPreviousMonth->toDateString()
) {
```